# Do the fissures from the Guardians of the Galaxy affect other titles?

Tags: marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Each Guardians of the Galaxy comic starts with the following:

> In the wake of two catastrophic annihilation events, the universe is in a fragile and weakened state.  With the fabric of space itself damaged, anomalous fissures are beginning to appear, fissures that could crack and spread, collapsing reality and letting in things that should not exist in our dimension.

I assume the "two events" to be the *Annihilation* and *Annihilation: Conquest* events, but was wondering whether the fissures mentioned here and encountered numerous times by the Guardians of the Galaxy popped up in any other titles?  Given they are universe-wide, it seems logical that other teams and/or heroes would encounter them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall them appearing outside the Abnett/Lanning titles(*Guardians of the Galaxy*, *Nova*, etc.).  The Marvel cosmic stuff was kept separate from the rest of the Marvel universe until very recently.  Characters died in the Abnett/Lanning story-lines and just reappear in other titles without incident.